# SQL Server dense_rank with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query,which is not returning proper result,
i want my query to return total of score for same user_id, so that each user_id will have only one record  with sum of all of its score.

My query is this:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank,
    user_id, 
    SUM(score) AS total_score
FROM 
    account_game
GROUP BY
    user_id, score
ORDER BY
    rank ASC
```

Query output is :

```
   rank user_id total_score
   1      2          4837
   2      1          600
   2      6          600
   3      1          30
   4      1          20
```

There should be three records with user_id 1,2,6

Expected result should be

```
  rank  user_id total_score
  -------------------------
   1     2      4837
   2     6      700
   3     1      650
```

Please suggest

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi, @wewesthemenace, i have updated my question with expected output

Comment: @PankajDas, great! See Tim's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As StuartLC commented, you can just remove the `score` from your `GROUP BY` and all should be fine:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by SUM(score) DESC) AS rank,
user_id, 
SUM(score) as total_score
FROM 
account_game
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Comment: Already updated,, but receiving error----- Column 'account_game.score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your answer before. I've deleted mine as it's just a duplicate.

Comment: Yup, got it ,thank to all,, now its working fine,, but i tried with @wewesthemenace answer,but it is deleted now, so how to mark it as correct answer

Comment: You could accept this one. I've deleted mine since it's just a duplicate.